# Troubleshooting git push - it asks for a user/pass

Tags: git, github

I'm using git on a new git linux computer. When I do `git push`, it me asks for user/password.

I've setup git properly, and in fact cloning the repo from github into a new folder works perfectly (using my public key, not the readonly copy). When I try to push from a previous clone I made to the same repo I get prompted for a user/pass.

Of course sshing into git@github.com works, and I made sure my public key is configured in github. Any ideas how to continue debugging?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What do you mean by previous repo? Check the url of the origin from the previous repo's `.git/config` file. If you had cloned using http, it will ask for user/pass.

Comment: You're right, the problem was an HTTP URL. By "a previous repo" I meant a previous clone of the same repo.

Answer (score 81):

this occurs because you did

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo
```

instead of

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

Comment: sometimes thats not an option!

Answer (score 57):

Try the following:

> git remote set-url origin [your git url, such as git@github.com:.../project.git]

Comment: After I run this I get "Enter passphrase for key '/u/.ssh/id_rsa':" which I know the password, but is there a way for it to stop asking this based on a key file being in place?

Comment: To avoid entering your password for your key with each push, try **ssh-add**. You'll need **ssh-agent** running to add the keys to your SSH agent.  [A simple man page here](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-6.html)

Comment: Whew you're the one persron who actually gave the solution instead of just saying what the problem is!

Comment: I did this and it still asks for username. Might only work with certain URLs.

Answer (score 7):

if your repo Url is: `https://github.com/abc/xyz.git`

set url from command line as: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:abc/xyz.git`

Replace  `https://github.com/` with `git@github.com:`

Comment: but not if the repo doesnt support ssh proto

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, there are three cases

```
1. git remote set-url github(remote repo name) https://github.com/id/a.git
    it asks ID/Passwd
2. git remote set-url github https://id@github.com/id/a.git
    it only asks Passwd
3. git remote set-url github git://github.com:id/a.git
    if you don't have a permission, it complains. So I can't use this for public server of github
```

all the commands are written to ".git/config"

Comment: Fixed my HTTPS was missing the username before @github.com

Answer (score 1):

for mac If you have git 1.7.10+ it needs to use credential-osxkeychain for password caching. Here is a nice explanation:

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Answer (score 1):

*May be this will help someone like me.*

Please find Git official article for caching your password

[image]

Link: https://help.github.com/en/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git

Commands:

1. Set Git to use the credential memory cache

   `> git config --global credential.helper cache`
2. Change default cache timeout

   `> git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'`

Comment: This caches the username and password, but will still have to enter both when cache expires.