# What is the best way to use Git, with HTTPS or with SSH?

Tags: git, github, https, ssh, bitbucket

I was wondering what is the safest way to use services like Github and Bitbucket. What are the differences between use HTTPS and use SSH?

Will it change how the repositories are invoked? I meant, I have seen commands like:

`git clone git@github.com:nsf/godit.git`

and

`git clone https://github.com/nsf/godit.git`

I'd like avoid problems like this:

[Troubleshooting git push - it asks for a user/pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813726/troubleshooting-git-push-it-asks-for-a-user-pass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences are mainly in the way authentication is done: for SSH, you'll use the keys to authenticate, and HTTPS will use username/password.

Note that to use SSH, you'll need to have write access to a repository, whereas HTTPS can be used for any type of a repository. [Here](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use)'s a useful help page with more details.

To avoid having to re-enter the password with HTTPS authentication, see this [article](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching).

Comment: Is possible to use both? I'd like to use HTTPS with Bitbucket and SSH with Github.

Comment: Sure it is. You specify each so called "remote" by means of an URL, and it is perfectly fine to have a mix of protocols in that list of remotes.