# Git asking for username and password

Tags: git, github

I recently had a project set up on my home system and created a repository on GitHub. I ran `git init` and added the files to the **staging area** and then **committed** the data, I had added to the project. However when I tried to run `git push -u origin main`, I was asked for a username and password (I hadn't set a password).

After a bit of research, I discovered that I had run `git remote add origin https://github.com/test/test.git` and I was being asked for a username and password because I was using the **HTTPS** protocol.

I fixed the issue by running `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:test/test.git`, which allowed me to push the changes over **SSH**. What I would like to know is why this happens, and what is the purpose of the **HTTPS** method, in this case. Is there any specific reason to use the **HTTPS** protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, http refers to the authentication method using username and password, not how assets are served, and it is generally not recommended unless you really need to use it ([for more, see the deprecation notice](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/) and the [HTTPS authentication docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github)).

SSH authentication is much easier if you take a moment to set it up (which it seems like you did) — this doesn't mean your images (or whatever) will be served to end-users over a different protocol, this is is how *you* are authenticating to GitHub to work with your repositories.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS cloning authorizes using credentials (email + password/personal access token). SSH uses your SSH key, which was probably already generated in your `~/.ssh` and added to your GitHub account, so it authorized without your input.

[image]

[What is the best way to use Git, with HTTPS or with SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15687811/3158312)

Comment: I don't have a password set up, I just used the ssh key method. I created and added my SSh key to GitHub but I was wondering what the HTTP method was used for, specifically.

Comment: I attached a link to an answer that dives deeper into this

Answer (score -3):

Basically, when you are interacting with github server via URL HTTPS git use the HTTP method to communicate to the server, but HTTP is insecure so git will require your credentials to authenticate the user with the remote server before you can do anything. But this method of authentication was deprecated some time ago, as the first comment said, it is a better choise to authenticate with SSH because this improves the security and integration of the data your sending to the remote.

You can read more about it here https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I understand that the HTTP protocol is insecure and the shh has  SHA encryption but I didn't know if it was reserved for any specific tasks. It being depreciated makes sense. I would give you an upvote but I'm not able to do that now.